# Set contains (Field name from Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap) not working

Tags: apex, map, set, contains

I have a below code to check the field name inside the set to field name inside the map.

```
 Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Test__JobApp__c.fields.getMap();
    set<string> fieldToSync = new Set<string>{'Id','Name','Test__order__c','Test__Name__c','Test__status__c'};
    
    for( Id jobAppId : NewMap.keySet()) {
        Thiru_Test__JobApp__c newjobApp = NewMap.get(jobAppId);
        Thiru_Test__JobApp__c oldjobApp = OldMap.get(jobAppId);
        List<String> changedFieldSet = new List<String>();

        for (String fieldName : fieldMap.keyset()) {
            try {
                if(newjobApp.get(fieldName) != oldjobApp.get(fieldName)){
                    if(fieldToSync.contains(fieldName)) {
                       changedFieldSet.add(fieldName);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Error: ' + e);
            }
        }
        fieldChangedMap.put(jobAppId, changedFieldSet);
    }
```

But it is not working. Below part is failing.

```
 if(fieldToSync.contains(fieldName)) {
     changedFieldSet.add(fieldName);
 }
```

But if I hard code the value for field name it's working fine. Could anyone please tell me what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field map returns keys in all lowercase, but you're using proper-casing. This is what's causing the problem. A better alternative would be to make sure the field is in the describe map. This eliminates the need for the try-catch block.

```
    for (String fieldName : fieldToSync) {
      if(fieldMap.containsKey(fieldName) && newjobApp.get(fieldName) != oldjobApp.get(fieldName)){
        changedFieldSet.add(fieldName);
      }
    }
```